# Bjt amp with 2 voltage sources bias point

Tags: circuit-analysis, amplifier, bjt, bias

I'm trying to bias the bjt amp with two voltage sources and make the collector of bjt at 0.5V to maximize output swing but the simulation give me too much different result, why? The collector current I choose - 5ma, R4 voltage drop - 1V, XMM1 shows 3.6V

[image]

Comment: What is the Beta of your transistor?

Comment: Beta is equal to 100

Comment: XXM1 shows the voltage drop across R3 resistor, not Vc voltage. XXM3 shows Vc voltage

Comment: XMM3 shows 1.4V what is same to VC1 - XMM1 = 5V - 3.6V = 1.4V. But I use 0.5V value of V collector to ground in my calculations

Comment: Did you include R5 resistor in your calculations?

Comment: No, I make it bigger to decrease it's influence to circuit. If I remove that the voltmeter output values doen't not change too much

Comment: For the  beta = 100 and Vbe = 0.7V I calculated Ic = 4.34mA and Vc voltage is Vc = 5V*10kΩ/(0.9kΩ + 10kΩ) - 4.34mA*10kΩ/(0.9kΩ + 10kΩ)*0.9kΩ = 1V

Comment: I can't understand the secod part of your equation where - 4.34ma

Comment: So to get Vc = 0.5V for Rc = 0.9kΩ and RL = 10kΩ  the collector current need to be equal to: Ic = (5V - 0.5V)/0.9kΩ - 0.5V/10kΩ = 4.95mA; and Ie = Ic*(beta +1)/beta = 5mA, so Re around 170Ω

Comment: I use a superposition to solve for Vc, Do you know superposition proncipel?

Comment: I need some refresh it in mind, may you get the link to quick guide?

Comment: 5V*10kΩ/(0.9kΩ + 10kΩ) - is a voltage drop on R5 to ground, but what is 4.34mA*10kΩ/(0.9kΩ + 10kΩ)*0.9kΩ?

Comment: I don't know any.  But in short, I treat Ic as a current source and I "short" Vcc voltage source and next I use a current divider rule to solve for Vc (without Vcc) Vc = - Ic * RL/(RL+Rc) * Rc

Comment: May you upload a part of schematic where it is?

Comment: @MaxMil To get the maximum swing, you need to take into account your minimum \$V_{CE}\$ as well as your emitter's quiescent voltage (needed for thermal compensation and other reasons, too.) You also haven't stated (did I miss it?) your desired signal gain. Or the input loading. (I see the output load you've given, at least.) But I guess you have to start somewhere.

Comment: @jonk How I can find centered Q-point using equations, I'm always getting different results in simulation or it's impossible to use DC analysis to find Q point with precission and there is always need to tune the circuit or use current sources?

Comment: @MaxMil You ***really*** can design these things. No, you do NOT need to tune them, once designed. They will just work. Even with part variations.

Comment: @MaxMil You are just hacking around without knowing what you are really supposed to do, I think. That's why you are getting things going all over the place.

Comment: @jonk I need Vc = 0,5V as Q point. I do: (5V - 0,5V) / 5ma = 900 Ohm; VR4 I choose 1V, so: (-5V - (-4V)) / 5ma = 200 Ohm, current goes through R2 - R1 I choose (5ma / betta) * 10 = 0,5 ma (10 times Ib); so Vb = -4V + 0,7V = -3,3V, R2 = (5V - (-3,3V)) / 0,5ma = 16,6 kOhm, R1 = (-3,3V - (-5V)) / 0,5ma = 3,4 kOhm. During simulation I get Vc to ground equal to 1,5 V but not 0,5 V that I choose as Q point. I can't understand where I design what I choose. Can you help how I need to correct my calculations to get 0,5V at Vc in simulation, not 1,5V that I have now?

Comment: @MaxMil At a guess, you haven't taken into account the base current loading on your Thevenin equivalent base resistance. You want a different Thevenin voltage, I think, or you need to otherwise account for your base loading (which is 10% of your divider current and not ignorable.)

Comment: @MaxMil Try \$16.3\:\textrm{k}\Omega\$ and \$3.7\:\textrm{k}\Omega\$ at the base, for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use adaptive biasing, like this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fomzuB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Yes, I'll try it!

Comment: How is it working? How R3, R4 voltage divider forms 2.5V?

Comment: We assume the current through R2 is much larger than the necessary base current. At 0.6v and 10Kohm, the current is 60uA; given 2.5v/1Kohm/beta=100 requires 2.5mA/100 = 25uA, this circuit is NOT a precise requlator. The Vce **does** depend upon beta; a lower value of R2/3/4 provides more tolerance for Beta uncertainty.

Comment: What is the purpose of C1? And why this shematic more useful than simple voltage divider?

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be an issue with the circuit you have drawn. I recreated the circuit and I see 4V and 2.5mA across R3 which is what one should expect

If you want Vc to be .5V instead of 1V you need to decrease the value of your Emitter resistor to increase the current though the transistor. R4 of ~170R is about what you would need.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXXlLm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

One thing to note is that if you modify the beta of the transistor up/down from 100  <del>it can have a significant effect on the Q point of the transistor</del> has only small effect on the Q point. This allows part-to-part variation (within reason) to be accommodated without having to individually trim the circuit to each transistor.

EDIT: I renumbered my resistors to match yours.

Comment: but what is an issue? I have 3.6V across R3 and I equal to 3.87ma, but need 4.5V and 5ma current. Is it always need to tune different parameters of circuit to set maximum correct Q point? Can I get in circuit what I derive in equations or I need to tune always?

Comment: Frosty - you have shown a well-known bias network (resistive divider at the base and Re-feedback) which ensures that any beta modification has just a little (negligible) effect on the Q-point (and NOT "significant"). This is because the BJT is a voltage-controlled device - and that is the reason we provide a base voltage as "stiff" as possible using the R1-R2 divider.

Comment: @LvW you are right and I've corrected the answer. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

There are many methods to find \$V_C\$ voltage. 
But if BJT is in the active region we can replace the \$I_C\$ with a current source. And the circuit diagram will look like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3X5Zk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**1** - I replace the current source with an open circuit and solve for \$V_C\$.

$$V_{C1} = V_{CC}\frac{R_L}{R_L+R_C}$$ (Voltage divide rule)

**2** - In this step, I "shot" the voltage source and solve for \$V_C\$

$$V_{C2} = -I_{R_C}*R_C $$

\$I_{R_C} = I_C * \frac{R_L}{R_L+R_C}\$ (current divider rule)

$$V_{C2} = -I_C * \frac{R_L}{R_L+R_C}*R_C $$

And finally we have:

$$V_C = V_{C1}+V_{C2} = V_{CC}\frac{R_L}{R_L+R_C}-I_C * \frac{R_L}{R_L+R_C}*R_C $$

Of Course, we could use Nodal analysis and solve for \$V_C\$

$$I_C+\frac{V_C}{R_L} - \frac{V_{CC} - V_C}{R_C} = 0$$

Therefore:

$$V_C = \frac{(V_{CC} - I_C R_C)R_L}{R_C+R_L}$$

In this type of a circuit, we can find voltage swing quite easy. 
The positive peak occurs when the BJT enters the cut-off region.

Hence

$$V_{Cmax} = V_{CC}\frac{R_L}{R_L+R_C} = 4.58V peak = 3.2V RMS $$

The negative peak is when the transistor is in the saturation region.

And the equivalent circuit looks like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f79Aak.png)</sup>

$$V_{Cmin} = \frac{R_L (R_E V_{CC} + R_C V_{cesat} + R_C V_{EE})}{R_C R_E + R_C R_L + R_E R_L} = -2.96Vpeak = -2.09VRMS $$

Or
$$V_{Cmin} \approx\frac{R_E}{R_E+R_C}(V_{CC}+|V_{EE}|)-V_{EE}+ V_{cesat}\approx(\frac{200\Omega}{200\Omega + 900\Omega}*10V)-5+0.2V \approx-2.98V peak $$

And the voltage gain will be around

$$A_V=\frac{R_C||R_L}{r_e + R_E}*\frac{\beta}{\beta + 1}\approx\frac{R_C}{R_E}\approx 4.5 V/V$$

Comment: very useful! I need refresh that method. Thanks too much.

Comment: @MaxMil A edit my post and added additional information.

Comment: Great, very useful calculations when two voltage sources biasing is used!